# What would the environment be inside a fish?

Tags: environment

In the body of a massive fish, about 200 miles long, is an island around half that length. This island is made up of deposited minerals from the sea, including large amounts of ancient bones and shells. It specifically sits across the fishe's mouth, throat, and stomach. This space is around halfway filled with seawater, and has 5 exits: The jaws, which can open to the full extent of the cavity, the 2 gills, which are always open but only below the waterline, and the 2 spiracles high in the roof of the skull, providing light and air to the island. The jaws open hourly, which is the main way nutrient get to the island. The fish moves at a constant 50mph across all latitudes through thunniform motion

**What effect would being in this fish have on the island's environment?**

Comment: No opening from the jaws through the island into the stomach?

Comment: A diagram or two (side view and top view) would really help here.  Also, 80mph as a constant speed is extremely fast for an aquatic creature - if this is achieved by the normal mechanism of moving the tail side to side then this will have a huge impact on anything inside.  So we need to know what its swimming motion is in order to answer.

Comment: This is a bit *too* absurd.  If the fish doesn't submerge, this is just a strange looking boat.  But assuming the fish submerges with closed spiracles, the container is essentially a diving bell, which moves a great distance under the water (enough to cover the spiracles), with pressure equalization through the gills.  Even if the island floats inside that chamber to avoid being submerged, the hourly opening to atmospheric pressure implies more than a little case of the bends.

Comment: Outside of fish, rice is the most efficient per-acre source of protein in the world. Inside of fish, it's much too dark to grow rice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Moist

Very moist. A living thing's insides are rather wet, even without going into the flesh itself. Good lord the humidity. Such a creature, despite(probably) not being warm-blooded, would generate a lot of heat. And the stench! Imagine being inside the mouth of someone who never brushed their teeth, ever, though I suppose if there are inhabitants living there they would eventually get used to the smell.